# aLaw audio format is not supported by HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

HTML5 audio player is not supporting aLaw audio format (in chrome and firefox) , is there any solution to play it, I don't want to use flash as a fallback.

Discription of aLaw (WAV) file :
Wave A-Law , 8000Hz , 64kbps , mono

ps: this format is working fine with mobile browsers (Including safari in desktop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an excellent solution on joomlavision to trigger webkitAudioAPI for aLaw WAVs

http://www.joomlavision.com/play-html5-audio-browser/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed , I have read it and tried it but it was unable to support that format.
Discription of aLaw (WAV) file :

Comment: Discription of aLaw (WAV) file :
Wave A-Law , 8000Hz , 64kbps , mono

Answer (score 0):

aLaw will be supported in Chrome 33 (see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=217772)